# Can't log in admin page of the django using the user i created

Tags: python, django

I did what the django tutorial said, but i still couldn't log in the localhost:8000/admin/
using the user I created. I check the database, there is no username 'admin'.
I created the user by :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User.objects.get(username__exact='john')
u.set_password('new password')
u.save()
```

Can anyone helps me ? please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

syncdb in general creates/updates the database, so from your statement:

> I check the database, there is no username 'admin'

I understand you must have somehow created your database. The first time you run syncdb you will be asked to create a super user. Right there you should insert your credentials.

However, if you lost this part you could later on use the django  shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

This will open a python shell with your django environment loaded. In that shell create the admin user as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User(username='admin', is_superuser=True, is_staff=True)
u.set_password('admin')
u.save()
```

Note that *is_staff* must be true for your new user to be able to login in the admin area
and *is_superuser* must also be true for the user to have all permissions.

Then go to localhost:8000/admin/ and login with your new 'admin' user.

Comment: I have also encountered this issue (I'm on Django 1.6) using SQLlite, and I've definitely made the superuser when prompted to. I keep having to use your work around. Do you know why?

Comment: Are you using the stock django user model? After running syncdb try to inspect the auth_user model and particularly the is_staff, is_superuser columns. Are they set correctly? Is there any chance you're loading any fixtures overriding your superuser? Sidenote: there's also a manage.py createsuperuser command which you can use as an alternative.

Comment: I think I'm using the stock django user model, not loading any fixtures (no idea what they are). When I do login, I can see the original 'superuser' user and they have all the right attributes ( is_staff, is_superuser)

Comment: In this case I expect you should be able to login using the 'superuser' user. I'm not sure what the problem could be I'm afraid..

Comment: I'm thinking it might be that my 'shell' is inside eclipse's console and could be inserting weird unicode characters? Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you go thru the whole procedure once again, cause you obviously missed some stuff.
Just start from the beginning.
You will see then what you have missed.

P.S.
If you have username john, you can't have the same user with the username admin.

I presume that you may have omitted to run **python manage.py syncdb**

Answer (score 0):

From the [second part of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#activate-the-admin-site), you need to do the following three things to enable the admin site. Did you miss any of them?

1. Uncomment "django.contrib.admin" in the INSTALLED_APPS setting.
2. Run python manage.py syncdb. Since you have added a new application to INSTALLED_APPS, the database tables need to be updated.
3. Edit your mysite/urls.py file and uncomment the lines that reference the admin – there are three lines in total to uncomment.

Comment: I didn't miss any of them . %>_<%

Comment: Can you check to see if the auth_* tables were created in your database? There should be seven of them ("auth_group" is the first one)